# $lookup on ObjectId's in an array of objects (Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this two schema:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', {
title : String,
text : String,
lang : { type: String, default: 'en'},
user : { type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
});



var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
email        : String,
name         : String,
rating       : [{
                    _id: false,
                    articleID: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Article'},
                    rate: Number
                }]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

and i want to calculate the average rating of an user (the average on all rating on its articles).

I tried this:

```
User.aggregate([
            { $unwind: "$rating" },
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "Article",
                    "localField": "rating.articleID",
                    "foreignField": "_id",
                    "as": "article-origin"
                }
            }//,
            //{ $match: { "article-origin.user" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(article.user) } }//,
            //{ $group : {_id : "$rating.articleID", avgRate : {  $avg : "$rating.rate" } } }
        ]).exec(function (err,result) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        });
```

but without success, the lockup always return the field article-origin null.

result:`{"_id":"590747e1af02570769c875dc","name":"name","email":"email","rating":{"rate":5,"articleID":"59074a357fe6a307981e7925"},"__v":0,"article-origin":[]}]`

Why this is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly no need for the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** operator since the group aggregation operation does not make use of the documents from the `articles` collection, it only needs a single field i.e. `articleID` for grouping.

There are two ways you can go about this. If your MongoDB server version is 3.4 or greater, then the **[`$divide`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/#exp._S_divide)**, **[`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#exp._S_reduce)** and **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)** operators can be applied here to calculate the average without resorting
to flatten the rating array first which can have some performance ramifications if the array is large.

Consider running the following pipeline:

```
User.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(article.user) } },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "avgRate": {
                "$divide": [
                    {
                        "$reduce": {
                            "input": "$rating",
                            "initialValue": 0,
                            "in": { "$sum": ["$$value", "$$this.rate"] }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$ne": [{ "$size": "$rating" }, 0] },
                            { "$size": "$rating" },
                            1
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]).exec(function (err, result) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

---

If using MongoDB version 3.2 then you would need to **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** the rating array first:

```
User.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(article.user) } },
    { "$unwind": "$rating" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "avgRate": { "$avg": "$rating.rate" }
        }
    }
]).exec(function (err, result) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

---

If for some reason you need the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** operation, you need to reference the collection name, not the model name, thus the correct aggregate operation should be

```
User.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$rating" },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "articles", /* collection name here, not model name */
            "localField": "rating.articleID",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "article-origin"
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "article-origin.user" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(article.user) } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "avgRate": { "$avg": "$rating.rate" }
        }
    }
]).exec(function (err, result) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```